# C# - add attribute like '.Length' to custom class

Tags: c#, list, attributes

I've playing around with a class that acts as a public interface for a  `private List<T>` attribute. I noticed that the `List<>` class has an attribute `Length` that tells you how many elements it contains.

This is an attribute you cannot alter, and on the intellisense appears with an image of a spanner next to it. It is not a method as it does not require `()` after coding the name.

I've seen attributes of this type before, but never used them in my own classes. Does anybody have any idea how I can replicate `Length` in my custom class?

Thanks,
Mark

Comment: `List<T>` has no `Length` but a [`Count` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/27b47ht3(v=vs.110).aspx). But i guess you are looking for [properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/x9fsa0sw.aspx) in general.

Comment: A property is in fact *backed* by a method. A method will be generated for you with the name `get_PropertyName`, though this is highly irrelevant to your question right now :)

Answer (score 5):

It's a property with no setter. If you're wrapping a `List<T>` you can just use it's Count as your own:

`public int Count {get {return _myPrivateList.Count; } }`

If you're using C# 6, you can use this:

`public int Count => _myPrivateList.Count;`

Answer (score 1):

If you currently have a class that contains a `List`, then you can take advantage of the [`Count`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/27b47ht3(v=vs.110).aspx) property already present on it by exposing a property that simply uses that :

```
public class YourExampleList<T>
{
     // Example of your inner list
     private List<T> _list { get; set; }
     // Use the Count property to expose a public "Length" equivalent
     public int Length { get { return _list.Count; } }   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is actually not a method, but a property.

So you could have define in your class

```
private List<string> myList = new List<string>();

public int NumberOfElements
{
    get { return this.myList.Count; }
}
```

A normal property would be defined such as

```
public bool ColumnNames { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
List<T> myList = new List<T>();
```

Now you can create your own implementation on your custom class. Something like:

```
   public int Length {get {return myList.Count; }}
```

Answer (score 1):

I must admit that your question is a bit vague. It sounds like you want know how to create a read only attribute / property. This can be achieved by creating a property wrapper for a private field member of your class as follow:

```
    class MyCustomClass
    {
        private int _length;

        public int Length
        {
            get { return _length; }
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Say for example you have a class like this:

```
public class MyClass
{
   private string _str;
   public MyClass()
   {
       _str = "Sample String";
   }

   public int Length
   {
       get
       {
           return _str.Length;
       }
   }
}
```

This is what's happening:

- We're declaring a private field at the start of the class named `_str`.
- In the constructor we're then assigning it a value of `"Sample String"`.
- After the constructor we're then declaring the public attribute `Length` of type `int`, and only giving it a `get` accessor. Like your example, this only allows the value to be read, and not set.
- Within the `get` we then tell it to return the value of `_str`'s length.

Using code similar to this you can implement a `Length` attribute for any custom class.